# Hibernate and Maven Java project hibernate.properties not found error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

So, I am trying to put this project to work, it's very simple.

I am using Maven to configure the dependencies, so I don't know much about it's usability yet.

The thread is that I can't build my EntityManager, for there is something wrong in the configuration file persistence.xml.

**[Project]**

[image]

**[Dependencies]**

[image]

**[Factory]**

[image]

**[Pom.xml]**

[image]

**[Test class]**

[image]

**[Persistence.xml]**

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

I don't know anymore what to do, tried everything that ocurred to me, searched everywhere i could and nothing solved this. Please, help me.

Comment: That's `hibernate` informing about .properties file not present. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving fully qualified path of your Entity class in persistence.xml

```
**<class>fully.qualified.path.of.the.entity</class>**
```

And, in your pom.xml add dependency for hibernate Entity Manager

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId></groupId>
<artifactId></artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hibernate-entitymanager</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- MySQL connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate 5.2.6 Final -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Try adding entity manager dependency version compatible with your hibernate version @Jorge do Carmo

Comment: Hello, I tried to add the version you posted there and it didin't show that logging message anymore, but it threw another exception: 

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class


Also, I tried to change the versions several times combining them but always I got the same result as before, this was the only differente result I got, so I'm assuming that's the right way... But yet there's a long way to go haha

If you know something more, please tell me.

Comment: Try adding this pom.xml dependencies.

Comment: Add dependency with respective to your relative Database, as I have added for mysql so I added its dependency in pom.xml. Do not forget to upvote if your problem is solved :) @JorgedoCarmo

Comment: Thank you. I've downloaded the compatible versions, so it worked right!

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem as Adya said.

I've downloaded the compatible versions of Hibernate libs and used the ojdbc driver so it worked all right. Pom.xml now looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jdc-developer</groupId>
  <artifactId>exercicio</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Ex</name>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

That's it